# Grails code fails when updating (works with a new object) a List with a no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have a domain object User that

```
   static hasMany = [following:User]
```

When I create  a new User I can select the users I want to follow in my multi select and it works fine but if I then update my User and change the 'following' list it errors on binding the parameters with

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.ListOrderedSet] to required
>   type [java.util.Set] for property 'following': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found
>
> at UserController.update(UserController.groovy:76) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:68

gsp code

```
<div class="clearfix ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'following', 'error')} ">
    <label for="following">
        <g:message code="user.following.label" default="Following" />

    </label>
    <div class="input">
    <g:select name="following" from="${com.social.User.list()}" multiple="multiple"
              optionKey="id" size="5" value="${userInstance?.following*.id}" class="many-to-many" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller code for the update:

```
def update() {
    def userInstance = User.get(params.id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (params.version) {
        def version = params.version.toLong()
        if (userInstance.version > version) {
            userInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this User while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    userInstance.properties = params
    // It will work if I blacklist the following param as below
    //bindData(userInstance, params, ['following'])

    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}
```

I currently have a workaround of

```
// Auto saving of following seems to fail so blacklist following param
// then set the list manually...
bindData(userInstance, params, ['following'])
userInstance.following = User.getAll(params.get("following") as List<BigInteger>)
```

in the update within the user controller but seems like there could be a better way???

Comment: Can you share your `UserController` code?

Comment: I just generated the edit view and controller action and it looks almost identical to what you are doing here and it worked fine for me.  One thing that I can think of is if you have another field in your GSP with the `name="following"` Maybe try and strip out everything in the GSP aside from your object's ID and your following select.

Comment: Still didnt work stripping everything out... did your work when updating the list as well as creating new? I have managed to work around this by blacklisting the following param then setting them manually with
userInstance.following = User.getAll(params.get("following") as List<BigInteger>)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue in grails version 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it was ultimately caused by the json-rest-api plugin that didn't handle correctly hibernate proxies obtained from the database.

See https://github.com/padcom/grails-json-rest-api/issues/14